# Is there a way to accept or decline the assigned task outside the Outlook desktop application?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

I see that there is no option for accepting or declining the assigned task through the Outlook Web Application (OWA).
Since I am using Exchange Server 2016, I've implemented a simple mail listener on the server machine, which catches the task when it is assigned.
The idea is to modify task properties using Exchange Web Services API, in the same way like the task is accepted through Outlook Desktop Application by clicking on *Accept* option.
Is there a way for doing this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer below sample code from Microsoft doing exactly what you are looking for.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Modify-efbca631

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer, but I didn't want to change task's Status property but the task's Mode property which have these values: "TaskMode.RequestAccepted", "TaskMode.RequestDeclined" etc..